# How to make a computed value for children in a array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a VueJS application and I'm using an array in the data object. The array exists of items with an 'updatedAt' time string, i want a computed value for each of these items that results in '1 hour ago' or 'two days' ago.

I got the function for calculating the 'time ago' right, but i want to make this function a computed property for each item in the array.

I have tried the following code

```
el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      {title: "Test1", updatedAt: "2019-06-06T15:55:46.000Z"},
      {title: "Test2", updatedAt: "2019-06-06T15:55:46.000Z"
    ]
  }, computed: {
     time_ago() {
        return moment(new moment(this.updatedAt)).fromNow();
     }
}
```

and by calling:

```
app.items[1].time_ago // returns undefined
```

I want it to return the result of the 'time_ago()' property of a item in the array. So for example:

```
app.items[1].time_ago // desired output: '2 days ago'
```

Comment: A `computed` property is not a property of the individual items. You probably want to define a `method` that you can call as `time_ago(app.items[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make sense as a `computed` if we'd be talking about a child component (repeated for each item in the array).

But you want the method in the parent, so that's why you should use: a `method`. In the sense it takes a parameter and calculates `time_ago` based on that parameter. The parameter could be either the child or the child's `updatedAt`:

```
methods: {
  time_ago(t) {
    return moment( new moment(t)).fromNow()
  }
}
```

Now you can use that method into a `computed` that maps it to each child:

```
computed: {
  itemsWithTimeAgo() {
    return this.items.map(i => ({...i, time_ago: this.time_ago(this.updateAt)}))
  }
}
```

Now you'll see that swapping `items` in your loop with `itemsWithTimeAgo`, each item will have the proper time ago in `item.time_ago`.

Let's see it working:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        title: "Test1",
        updatedAt: "2019-06-06T15:55:46.000Z"
      },
      {
        title: "Test2",
        updatedAt: "2019-06-06T15:55:46.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    itemsWithTimeAgo() {
      return this.items.map(i => ({ ...i,
        timeAgo: this.timeAgo(i)
      }))
    },
    logger() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.itemsWithTimeAgo, null, 2);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    timeAgo(i) {
      return moment(new moment(i.updatedAt)).fromNow();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre v-text="`itemsWithTimeAgo: ${logger}`" />
</div>
```

**Note:** purposefully, in the snippet I used the item as a parameter, while in the snippets above I used the item's `updatedAt` directly. Arguably, the method taking the less complex parameter is insignificantly faster. So, in principle, you want to pass the `updatedAt` directly. However, don't overdo it. The gain in performance, while arguable, it's far less than the loss in readability, as the scale of the app grows.